# How binding java.util.Set using Spring MVC 5?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jpa, set

I have a problem with binding JSP form using java.util.Set .
  I'm using JPA with Hibernate and i can't change  java.util.Set to java.util.List, because this will affect my database model.

My exception is:

> [javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'phones[0]'

I understand this exception. But i dont know how binding java.util.Set in JSP form.

Can someone help me?

```
@Entity
public class Phone implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7507976788394149092L;

    @Id
private String ddd;

@Id
private String number;

public String getDdd() {
    return ddd;
}

public void setDdd(String ddd) {
    this.ddd = ddd;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(String number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public void setPrincipal(boolean principal) {
    this.principal = principal;
}
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Client {

        @Id
@Column(columnDefinition = "CHAR(11)")
private String cpf;

@ManyToMany
private Set<Phone> phones = new HashSet<Phone>();

public String getCpf() {
    return cpf;
}

public void setCpf(String cpf) {
    this.cpf = cpf;
}

public Set<Phone> getPhones() {
    return phones;
}

public void setPhones(Set<Phone> phone) {
    this.phones = phone;
}
}
```

and

```
...
<label for="dddPhone">DDD - Fixo</label>
<springForm:input path="phones.ddd" type="number" class="form-control" id="dddPhone" placeholder="DDD" />
...
```

Comment: You can't change your entity to use a List but... you could use a custom object as your form and put a List there for the binding. Then, convert that to the required set on your entity.

Comment: That's a great idea. Thanks! =D